# Shrink the entire view when resizing the window

Tags: css, angular, bulma

I want to shrink the entire view when resizing the window. In mobile view, the view should be a shrunken version of the desktop view. Something similar to the https://www.cbioportal.org/ website. If we resize, the entire view is being shrunken. In the frontend i'm using Angular and bulma. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the "responsive" meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

This will revert to default behavior of browser which shows the entire viewport width.

Comment: I did, this isn't working. Does bulma have anything to do with it?